# Linked Hashmap in Python

Tags: python-2.7, linkedhashmap

I need to create a linked hash map for a set of strings where key is the word and values are a linked list with each node containing occurrence of that word in that string and id of that string. For a hashmap I know we have to create a dictionary but how to get a data structure like this?

Comment: Normally, we think of `LinkedHashMap` as having ordered keys. Is that a requirement for you too?

Comment: No such ordering is required.

Comment: Just make a dictionary if strings to lists if tuple.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, it's often most convenient to achieve these types of data structures by nesting the built-in data structures. For example:

```
{word: [(occurrence, id), ... ], ... }
```

For the dict values you could use a list of lists or a tuple of tuples, but I'd guess that while the collection of nodes will be altered to over the course of your program, the nodes themselves will not, which works with the mutability of those respective data structures.